# Android Studio Problemas con la vista de diseño

Tags: android, studio

Hola buenas estoy teniendo el siguiente problema:

A la hora de diseñar el layout en la pestaña de Diseño, dispongo de una barra de herramientas a la derecha llamada "Atributos" que me mostraba todos los atributos del objeto seleccionado y de esta manera me facilitaba personalizarlo, mi problema es que algo he tocado que ahora no me aparecen la mitad de las opciones y no se como arreglarlo.

Opciones tales cómo "gravity, padding, hint" ya no aparecen ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo, alguna idea?

Comment: En la barra de la parte derecha, tienes las properties de los controles, pero agrupadas de diferente manera. Tienes un apartado donde te muestra las que tienes modificadas, otra que te muestra las más comunes, otra que te muestra todas las que existen. Cada sección se activa y desactiva plegándose o desplegándose al pulsar sobre el nombre de la sección "Common Attributes", "Declared Atributes", etc. Mira en [este](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor) enlace.

Comment: Las tengo todas desplegadas, pero aún así hay opciones que no me aparecen, por ejemplo en un textView no me aparece la opción de elegir el tamaño del texto...

Comment: ¿No tienes ningún error en el XML? Esta información se muestra al interpretar lo que tienes en el XML. [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982649/android-studio-not-showing-attributes-for-button/53982897) tienes posibles soluciones.

Comment: ¡¡SOLUCIONADO!! Borrando las carpetas que indica en el "Extrem step" se ha solucionado. Muchísimas gracias!! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto puede ser un detalle de sincronización del proyecto con sus recursos. Si no ves un error o ya corregiste el error y este no se ve reflejado, debes invalidar caché, esto puede provocar 2 cosas: que se pueda ver bien tu layout o que los errores en los recursos se muestren.

Realiza la eliminación del caché mediante:

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]